# Predictable network interface names doesn't work

Tags: networking, interface

I have a problem with moving into predictable network interfaces - if i rename eth01 into enp1s0 - can't login (interface doesn't starting up). I checked `/etc/default/grub` for `net.ifnames=0` - not found. Also checked `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` but file doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

check if there are links:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jan 31  2016 80-net-name-slot.rules -> /dev/null
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    9 Jan 31  2016 80-net-setup-link.rules -> /dev/null
```

You have to delete it...